# Most accurate way to interpolate data and find the peak?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

The data I have is always on a second degree polynomial (quadratic function). I want to find the peak of the interpolated function as accurately as possible.

[image: Data sample points]

So far I've been using `interp1d` and then extract the peak value using `linspace` and a simple `for` loop. Although you can use a large number of newly generated samples in `linspace` you can still be more precise using the derivative of the fitted polynomial.
 I haven't found a way to do that using `interp1d`.

Now the only function I've found that returns the fitted polynomial coefficients is `polyfit`, but this fitted function is quite inaccurate (most of the time the function doesn't even go through the data points).

[image: <code>interp1d</code> and <code>polyfit</code> functions]

I've tried using `UnivariateSpline` and the fitted function seems to be quite accurate and it's very simple to get the derivative spline and its root.

Other polynomial fitting functions (`BarycentricInterpolator`, `KroghInterpolator`, ...) state that they are not computing polynomial coefficients for reasons of numerical stability.

How accurate is `UnivariateSpline` and its derivatives, or are there any better options out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I went with `polyfit`. Although the fitted function didn't go exactly through the data points the end result was still good. From the returned coefficients I got the desired x and y coordinates of the peak.

Comment: What about taking the derivative of the points, then using a linear fit and looking for the zero crossing.  Would that be more accurate and a simpler regression to compute.  Just wondering, as I too need to find the interpolated maximum.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to find the min/max of a second degree polynomial why not do this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import KroghInterpolator
import numpy as np

x=range(-20,20)
y=[]
for i in x:
    y.append((i**2)+25)

x=x[1::5]
y=y[1::5]

f=KroghInterpolator(x,y)
xfine=np.arange(min(x),max(x),.5)
yfine=f(xfine)

val_interp=min(yfine)
print val_interp

plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.plot(xfine, yfine)
plt.show()
```

Comment: But this method still relies on the step size of `np.arange`, which is in this case _0.5_. I'd like to get the maximum of the quadratic function down to float/double precision.

Comment: @TjazBrelih It does give you float/double point precision. Change `y.append((i**2)+25)` to `y.append((i**2)+25.086)` . Then run the program. The interpolation at 0.5 spacing finds the minimum value even though that value didn't exist in the original data you pass in.

Comment: This only works if the function isn't shifted along the x axis. When you change `y.append((i**2)+25)` to `y.append(((i+0.2)**2)+25)`, you wont find the true peak, only the max/min value of the interpolated function sampled at the interval of _0.5_.

Comment: @TjazBrelih I have no idea what you are talking about. The script works fine even with a shift in x-axis...you just need to change the spacing of xfine to be a bit smaller (for your example a spacing of 0.1 works perfectly). Your original question asked for a way of finding the peak y value accurately...my solution does just that. Replace the bits of my code that generate data with your data and you have a solution.

Comment: The problem is that the shift in x axis is essentialy random. Another thing is that I don't have just one set of data to interpolate, there are many and each has a shift of their own. This method would work if you would use the smallest possible spacing for `np.arange`.
In the end I opted for `polyfit` method since it returns the actual coefficients of the quadratic function so you get the x and y coordinates of the peak by deriving them by "hand".